# Gallery/list of advertisements for a site

Tags: feature-request, advertising

When I am viewing pages, I sometimes see an ad that I don't have time to investigate at the moment, and I don't always bookmark them.

I believe the system needs to have some way or search where I can see the currently running advertisements.

Ideally this would also be the official list of all the community ads.

As a regular users of serverfault I see the ads running in the sidebar.  In a several cases I have  investigate the product, and a couple cases actually purchased something because of the advertisement.

Recently I had remember seeing one interested and I wanted to find it again, so I went to the main page, and just kept re-refreshing the page a lot.  This creates needless traffic, may mess up your stats, and is not very easy to find a particular ad.

Comment: Also the now-defunct http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-advertisement-gallery